# CircleCI Lint Test fails after I lint code locally

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

I am new to CircleCI and working on a project that runs CirclCI on GitHub whenever code is pushed to the remote repo.

Before pushing, I run `yarn lint` and I still get a failing test from CircleCI.
[image: err]

Also, just to be clear, when I run `yarn lint` there are no changes that are shown in my git locally. It is green displaying no changes were made by the linting.

[image: branch]

**CircleCI HomePage:**
[image]

**Additional Context**:

I am running a Mac and CI is running Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `yarn prettier --check .` to solve this problem.